# add new option to dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I searched around and i saw some codes : "how to add a new option to a dropdown".

This is my dropdownlist :

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

My dropdown is populated using database. I want to add a new option without refreshing the page.

and this is my code for adding a option in it

```
console.log(nov+kategorija);
                $('#DropDownList1')
                   .append(new Option(kategorija,nov))
                     .val(nov);
```

But it's not work.

Some help ?

Maybe for someone this may be a stupid question :D

Comment: Please post the rendered **HTML**, not the server-side code.

Comment: @PeterKA i found the answer :) And answered my own question. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I realize that it is a better way to target elements by class.

Added class to my dropdown :

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="dropdown"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And then in jQuery :

```
var dropdown = $('.dropdown');

                dropdown.append(new Option(kategorija, id));
```

Where kategorija is the text and the id is the value of the new option :)